# Bash conditional returning an error of bash: =: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [[ "$PROXY_URL"==https* ]]; then
    echo "Woohoo"
else
    echo "Woohoo"
fi
```

Running `$PROXY_URL = "https://yolo" ; ./proxyEnv.sh` gives me output of:

```
bash: =: command not found
Woohoo
```

What does the "bash: =: command not found" refer to?

Comment: beware of spaces: `varname=value`. The same goes for condition inside `[[ ]]`: put a space after the `==`

Comment: Same issue with `if [[ "$PROXY_URL"== https* ]]; then`

Comment: In addition to not having spaces, the _assignment_ should not have `$` and _should_ have `export` (or `declare/typeset -x`) since you want it available to a different script.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will identify your problem here.

Comment: ...it's also [BashPitfalls #16](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#foo_.3D_bar). And your script is, further, falling into [BashPitfalls #10](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D.3B_then_...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string comparison [should  have spaces around the comparator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html):

```
if [[ "$PROXY_URL" == https* ]]; then
    echo "Woohoo https"
else
    echo "Woohoo no https"
fi
```

Also, that's not how you pass environment variables to bash scripts. You have two options:

```
PROXY_URL="https://yolo" ./proxyEnv.sh
```

or

```
export PROXY_URL="https://yolo"; ./proxyEnv.sh
```

The first option assigns (*without* the `$`) the value to the symbol and then uses that environment for the script (without the `;` separating them). It only exists for the script.

The second option exports that symbol to the current environment, which the script inherits.

Comment: Still same issue `bash: =: command not found`.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski See my update.

Comment: Thank you! It's been one of those long days.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I didn't even notice myself until I noticed your reply to Derlin.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Feel free to Accept it if it fixed the problem (so the question doesn't stay open).

Comment: Will do once the timer runs out.